# Using HTTPAdapter and Receive.dll throws error

Tags: c#, sql-server, iis, biztalk

I am using BizTalk 2020. I have a webapp that calls a webapi that calls BizTalk through IIS. When run the request I get an error in BizTalk:

*There was a failure executing the receive pipeline: "Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines.XMLReceive, Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Source: "XML disassembler" Receive Port: "HTTPREC" URI: "/BTHTTP/BtsHttpReceive.dll" Reason: Finding the document specification by message type "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/#string" failed. Verify the schema deployed properly.*

I verified my schemas and found they all deployed. I used a generated instance for my message.

```
<ns0:Select xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TableOp/dbo/MainData">  <ns0:Columns>LocationID,BulletinLevel,NotifyUponCompletion,SupervisorName,CrewMemberID,AircraftID</ns0:Columns>
  <ns0:Query></ns0:Query>
</ns0:Select>
```

I validated it. I looked in BizTalk Hub and found a resumeable message for the SND port from the previous day. I opened the message and this was the contents of the body:

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">&lt;Select xmlns="05/TableOp/dbo/MainData"&gt;&lt;Columns&gt;LocationID,BulletinLevel,NotifyUponCompletion,SupervisorName,CrewMemberID,AircraftID&lt;/Columns&gt;&lt;/Select&gt;</string>
```

Not sure why it added the xmlns as a string to the message. I've rebuilt and redeployed several times restarting the hosts after updating.  My ports are using XMLReceive and XMLTransmit pipelines. The process receives a message then makes a call to SQL server to run the select.

Here is my orchestration: [image]

Do I need to add `<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">` to my message before running the request?

I checked IIS, pipeline settings, ISAPI module settings and asp.net version, everything looks correct.

UPDATE (12/08/2021) Created a custom pipeline that removes the  element that is wrapping the original message. It processes, but I get an 500 Internal Sever error from Receive.dll. If the message is being modified in the pipeline, not sure why the Receive.dll is not showing a status of 200.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This was the message body I found from a previous run (SND PORT) <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">&lt;Select xmlns="05/TableOp/dbo/MainData"&gt;&lt;Columns&gt;LocationID,BulletinLevel,NotifyUponCompletion,SupervisorName,CrewMemberID,AircraftID&lt;/Columns&gt;&lt;/Select&gt;</string>

Comment: Why does your message have an Microsoft Namespace?  Can you add your schema to the question?

Comment: Also how are you creating the message that is being sent to the send port?  I suspect you are just setting it as a string in the Orchestration, rather than a XML payload that you then use a Flat FIle schema and send port to send. And for the send port, what adapter are you using?

Comment: The schema was generated by the wizard, it contains Select and SelectResponse schemas.  Here is the request. <ns0:Select xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TableOp/dbo/MainData">
  <ns0:Columns>LocationID,BulletinLevel,NotifyUponCompletion,SupervisorName,CrewMemberID,AircraftID</ns0:Columns>
  <ns0:Query></ns0:Query>
</ns0:Select>   When the request is made and sent to the receive dll, It is adding the <string> element with the xmlns attribute.  On the receive location I use a pass through, then use an external class to strip out the <string> element.

Comment: I use HTTPAdapter on the send port, with XML Rec, XML Transmit  pipelines.  It looks like my message is not getting modified since I get the same error on the Sql req and the return response to the website.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to update to question with new information.

Comment: How can the send port be an HTTP one, when it looks like the created schema is a WCF-SQL one?

Comment: Two send ports. First is the WCF-SQL, its on a request/response port. The second is the HTTP port that returns the results form the Sql response

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it is using a schema with internal Microsoft namespace, and trying to use for something that it isn't supposed to be for.   Map the SQL response to a schema that you've created with a custom namespace and send that out via the Send Port instead.